# каким образом лучше всего выводить большое количество данных БД

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, big-data

Если мне нужно вывести 80 тыс. записей из одной таблицы в БД, при этом для каждой записи подставить по айди заголовок из второй таблицы, то каким образом мне практичнее всего это делать, чтобы не возникло проблем с оперативной памятью на сервере и прочих беспокойств.
Хотелось бы узнать по каким векторам искать информацию.

Вот что я могу на данный момент:

```
$komrads = DbQuery::fetchAll("SELECT * FROM everyone_in_andorra");
foreach ($komrads as $komrad) {

    $vernacular = DbQuery::fetchOne("SELECT language FROM kgb_list WHERE komradid = '".$komrad['id']."' LIMIT 1");
    if (!$vernacular) {
        echo $komrad['id']."<br> Не владеет языками";
    } else {
        echo $komrad['name']." - ".$vernacular['language']."<br>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Разумеется это надо делать одним запросом, что то вроде `select id, name, (select language from kgb_list where komradid=A.id limit 1) as lang from everyone_in_andorra A`

Comment: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html

Comment: @Mike, а для `не владеет языками` второй запрос?

Comment: @avp второй не нужен. Если в строке "lang = NULL", т.е. пустое значение - значит не владеет.

Comment: @АндрейТаланин тут join плохо применим, потому как надо выбрать одну запись (limit 1) из нескольких. Это при обычном join достаточно сложно в реализации, особенно на MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `SELECT * FROM everyone_in_andorra` - так плохо. Вам точно нужны  все записи если да укажите их все таки, так будет лучше.

2) Пагинация по  таблице должна быть самый простой способ (и он же не очень хороший) `limit` `offset`, лучше конечно будет себя вести обычный `where id < ? and id > ?`

3) Join в принципе тут уместен но в больших таблицах плох. Можно использовать связь по `id` с помощью `IN` - есть и другие варианты.

4) 80 000 - совсем не много не должно прям сильно убивать систему, но все в руках кодера конечно

5) Не забывайте  конечно про индексы в таблицах это важно.